# Are `zval *retval` argument and the `zval *` return value of the `zend_call_method` the same?

Tags: c, php-internals, zend-api

Is the `zval *` value returned by the zend api method `zend_call_method` same as the `zval *retval` argument passed into it?

I can see that `zend_call_method` is declared in `zend_interfaces.h`. I tried grepping the source directory for its definition, but couldn't find it. Where is it defined?

I have seen some extensions using the same variable as `retval` argument, and also to receive the return value of the function call. Is that the expected usage?

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that they are not the same.

When calling `DateTime::setTimezone` with `zend_call_method`, passing the `zval *` of the original `DateTime` object as `*retval` increments it's refcount by 1.

```
zend_call_method_with_1_params(date, php_date_get_date_ce(), NULL, "settimezone", date, tz);
```

Whereas the following code does not

```
date = zend_call_method_with_1_params(date, php_date_get_date_ce(), NULL, "settimezone", NULL, tz);
```